# mySQL 5.7.13 source installation not creating mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, sockets, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-5.7

Using default value installation, I have installed mysql 5.7.13. from source using the instructions from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing-source-distribution.html
I then initialized the Data Directory as instructed here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html
This is installed on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

Starting the server using this:

```
bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

Tells me to check the log files error.log.
Error.log says

```
2016-07-15T22:16:43.460297Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-07-15T22:16:43.862401Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see$
2016-07-15T22:16:43.863013Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider$
2016-07-15T22:16:43.863502Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.13) starting as process 1996 ...
2016-07-15T22:16:43.864532Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' c$
2016-07-15T22:16:43.893029Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-07-15T22:16:43.893057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-07-15T22:16:43.893080Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-07-15T22:16:43.893084Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2016-07-15T22:16:43.893086Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-07-15T22:16:43.894664Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-07-15T22:16:43.902772Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-07-15T22:16:43.908310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-07-15T22:16:43.932802Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-07-15T22:16:43.942146Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of se$
2016-07-15T22:16:43.952791Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2016-07-15T22:16:43.952931Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibdata1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-07-15T22:16:44.015448Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibdata1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.015683Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2016-07-15T22:16:44.197808Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2016-07-15T22:16:44.296354Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2016-07-15T22:16:44.296394Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2016-07-15T22:16:44.296404Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2016-07-15T22:16:44.296422Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-07-15T22:16:44.319575Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.319763Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2016-07-15T22:16:44.340836Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2016-07-15T22:16:44.345684Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.345696Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.345779Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.353886Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2016-07-15T22:16:44.353917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.354865Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.354886Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.355467Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: sys_virtual table created
2016-07-15T22:16:44.356452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-07-15T22:16:44.406828Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.13 started; log sequence number 0
2016-07-15T22:16:44.406972Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Unknown error 1146
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408277Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408377Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408381Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting


2016-07-15T22:16:44.408393Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408428Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408430Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408433Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408435Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408477Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408482Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408483Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408485Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408486Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408488Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408490Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408491Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408493Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408494Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408496Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408497Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408499Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408500Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408502Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408503Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408505Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408506Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408508Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408510Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408511Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408513Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408514Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408516Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408517Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408519Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408520Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408522Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408523Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408525Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408526Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-07-15T22:16:44.408548Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
```

And launching mysql_updgrade

```
bin/mysql_upgrade
```

I get an error message saying:

> mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to
>   the MySQL server Upgrade process encountered error and will not
>   continue.

The issue is that the sock file does not exist anywhere. It just doesn't exist. I've searched using `find` and `locate` and i'm 100% sure it is nowhere on my server. Looking at `my.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

None of these default values are correct. So i changed my my.cnf file appropriately match where everything is. Since mySQL was installed in /usr/local/mysql .

Altered my.cnf file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

[client]
#host           = 127.0.0.1
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /tmp/mysqld.pid
socket          = /tmp/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr/local/mysql
datadir         = /usr/local/mysql/data
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/local/mysql/share
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /usr/local/mysql/data/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Now, I am still getting the same issue. The socket file is simply not being created, no matter what folder I say the my.cnf is in and which permissions. I have tried creating the file itself, but it produces the same result.
And yes, I have made sure that the my.cnf is the default file for mySQL. The port is open in iptables and mySQL user does have ownership/access to all the files that the mysql config is directing it to.

I'm running this on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with apache2 installed. And the server is running in Virtual Box. I am accessing the server through Putty.

I've been stuck on this for days and am at a complete loss on what to do now after attempting all solutions I can find in other questions on this site and others. I can provide any and all info/logs needed to help answer this question.

I would really appreciate any and all help on this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. There was a line in the error.log concerning the key buffer size that i was ignoring. After commenting out these two lines:

```
#myisam-recover = BACKUP
#key_buffer = 16M
```

I deleted the default data directory and reinitialized the data directory. Mysql then started with no problems.